# How to make a WCF call to be always passed through a particular method first and then to the actual method

Tags: c#, wcf

I have been asked this question in an interview that what can be done to make a WCF call to be always passed through a particular method first in the contract and then to the actual method that is being called?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking something like IParameterInspector. Check this out. It provides After and Before Call.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2011/04/25/wcf-extensibility-iparameterinspector/